# Flex grid with relative height and different sizes in CSS

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

**What I want to achieve**

I am working on a grid like this:
[image]

This is no problem with fixed widths and heights. But I can't get it to work with relative widths and heights. Every box needs to be a square. They have a width of 100%. Height should be the same, so not hardcoded. Every Box will display an image in center/middle.

No matter what I try (bootstrap grid, flex, hardcoded paddings etc.) I can't get it quite done.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Please include your code, thanks

Comment: I don't get you ... you don't want to keep fixed height but you want contents to determine their parents height ? Aren't those opposites. Unless all the images equate to same height, **how do you expect a flexible container to be fixed without giving fixed height**.

Comment: Well I don't get the problem. Theoretically I could get the width of the div with js and set the height equal to that with js. But I guessed there would be a better solution. I will add a code construct to maybe clarify my intention.

Comment: @kingardox Why not using [CSS grid layout](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid)? It has good browser support. Also why not using tables? I mean you can achieve this via `display: table-row`/`display: table-cell`. Flexbox is about 1D layout, it won't resolve this completely without extra Javascript.

Comment: @kingardox If you are OK with tables and/or grid, I can post you example.

Comment: if it is for a full window's width, grid, flex and vw units could be used together https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JJwaox

Answer (score 1):

Check the below. I think this is what you need.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.big-image {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.small-image {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.small-images .small-image:nth-child(1) {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/300"></div>
  <div class="small-images">
    <div class="small-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/100"></div>
    <div class="small-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/100"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-images">
    <div class="small-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/100"></div>
    <div class="small-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/100"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the right idea but this only works because the image dimensions fit exactly. In my case the content of the boxes is changing. So I wan't the boxes to be always the same size regardless of the content of the boxes.

Comment: Since you mentioned hardcoded paddings I assumed this is allowed. Code is adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

try using jQuery to set the height of the div's equal to their width.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        giveHeight();
        $(window).resize(function () { giveHeight() });
    });
    function giveHeight() {
        $(".col-xs-6").each(function () {
            $(this).height($(this).css("width"));
        });
    }
</script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 red">BIG</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-xs-6 red">1</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 red">2</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 red">3</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 red">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```